# How Scala case method usage for pyspark

Tags: scala, pyspark

In scala, when I have a RDD list like :
`List(("a",1),("a",2),("b",3),("b",4),("b",5),("a",6))`, and I want to calculate the `avg` number for each character.

Like for `a` it shows 3 times with the value count 1+2+6 = 9, so the result I expect is `(a, 3)`.

In Scala I can write the code like below:

```scala
val newRdd = rdd.aggregateByKey((0,0))((t,v) => {(t._1 + v, t._2 + 1)}, (t1, t2) => {(t1._1 + t2._1, t1._2 + t2._2)})
val result = newRdd.mapValues{
    case(num, count) => {
        num/count
    }
}
```

So the result RDD will return the one I expected.
However, how could I explain the case(num/count) to pyspark?

I've tried:

```
avg_rdd_2 = avg_rdd_1.mapValues(lambda x, y : x / y)
```

But I will get the error below.

> 21/12/24 01:27:02 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 6)
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 619, in main
> process()
> File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 611, in process
> serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
> File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 259, in dump_stream
> vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
> File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 74, in wrapper
> return f(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2278, in 
> map_values_fn = lambda kv: (kv[0], f(kv[1]))
> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that we have an RDD:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 3), ("b", 4), ("b", 5), ("a", 6)])
```

In your Scala example you first aggregated by key, the same could be done using:

### `groupByKey`

```py
new_rdd = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: sum(x) / len(x))

print(new_rdd.collect())
# [('b', 4.0), ('a', 3.0)]
```

### `aggregateByKey`

```py
new_rdd = rdd.aggregateByKey(
    (0, 0),
    lambda x, y: (x[0] + y, x[1] + 1),
    lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]),
)
result = new_rdd.mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])
print(result.collect())
# [('b', 4.0), ('a', 3.0)]
```

### `reduceByKey`

```py
result = (
    rdd.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
    .mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])
)

print(result.collect())
# [('b', 4.0), ('a', 3.0)]
```